# How can I open a URL and then open another URL attached to a keyword?

Tags: python, url, bots

***Basically, I want the script to be able to open a URL and then search for the keyword and open the link attached to the keyword.***

Here's an example, I want to open Supreme New York's URL for Jackets and I want to open the URL for a jacket called Cheetah Hooded Jacket (leaked before site has been updated) that's on the Supreme Jacket URL. I need to be able to do this seconds after the site updates, so I wouldn't be able to know the URL beforehand to just open it from the start. I must open the first URL and find the second using a keyword and then open it using Python.

I know already how to open a URL:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets')
```

But I don't know how to use a keyword to find the URL attached to it.

Comment: Consider `selenium` - it's `.find_element_by_link_text` documented here sounds like it'd be useful for this: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are looking for the contents of the page, you need to make a request to the page and not just open it.  For example, to get the content of your page using the `requests` module (get it through pip) you would write the following:

```
import requests

req = requests.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets')
req.raise_for_status()

content = req.text()
```

Then, you could use regular expressions or the `BeautifulSoup` module (also through pip), which processes html, to find the link you want.
Using regular expressions, your code would look like so:

```
import re

# get content

for match in re.findall(r'<a.*>', content):
    if match and 'some criteria' in match.group(0):
       new_url = re.search('href=\"(.*)\"', match.group(0))

       if new_url:
           new_url = new_url.group(1)
```

From here on, just open `new_url` in webbrowser and you are set to go.
As always, look these modules up on your own so you know how to adapt my code to what you need and solve other similar problems in the future.

*P. S. I don't know if the regular expressions I used are perfect for your use case, but you get the idea.*

Hope this helps!

#### Links

requests: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

BeautifulSoup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

regular expressions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html